# R: DT package (Version 0.1.56 -> development version) column filters are not working

Tags: r, dt

I have a problem with **DT package (Version 0.1.56 -> development version)**.

DT Filters are not working,

Here is reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

data <- structure(list(x = c(71063, 71063, 71063, 71063, 71063, 
                           71063), y = c(200183, 200183, 200183, 200183, 200183, 200183
                           ), z = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1")), .Names = c("x", 
                                                                                         "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L
                                                                                        ))
data$z <- as.factor(as.character(data$z)) 
data$x <- as.numeric(as.character(data$x)) 

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tableId')),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tableId = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data, filter="top",options = list(pageLength = 100, lengthMenu=c(100,200,300,400,500,600)))
    })

  }
)
```

At the beginning i thought it is a problem with type of the column (unknown or character) but that does not seem to be the thing!

I have tried:

```
data$z <- as.factor(as.character(data$z)) ...
```

Column type has been changed however filter still was unavailable.

***With the CRAN version of DT everything was working smooth**...Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Seems like a bug to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know now why those filters are not working. It is not bug. These columns do not have more than one unique value -> so there is nothing to filter...